# How to restart KDE window decorations without loosing the running X session

Tags: kde, window-manager, kubuntu, window-decorations

For graphics editing of some special graphics formats I am using a java program called [imagej](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/). This has the annoying bug that one special function tends to kill KDE's window decorations if it has too many images open. At the moment I solve this by switching to a `tty` and restarting the `kdm` service. The downside of this solution is that I am kicked out of my running X session which may result in some lost work if there were still unsaved files open.

Is there another way to restart my window decorations without getting logged out of my current X session?

As it may be of importance:

- Kubuntu 12.04
- KDE 4.10 from the `kubuntu-ppa/backports` repo. Same problem already occurred with the stock KDE 4.8.5 from kubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try `kwin --replace` or `DISPLAY=:0 kwin --replace` if you're not in X.
[Source](http://community.kde.org/KWin/Hacking#Handling_the_case_when_KWin_crashes)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. Only one short addendum: it's useful to put an ampersand `&` behind the commands if one does not want to block this console for the rest of the session.

Comment: you're right, or you could just run the command in krunner if you have access to it.

Comment: Decades pass but KDE reliability never changes, it still crashes many times a day, like 11 years ago... But it manages to be so great otherwise that we keep tolerating this... I just wonder how many KDE generations will the problem survive... :-)

Comment: @Ivan It's a feature ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the updated answer for KDE 5:

```
kwin_x11 --replace
```

Comment: `kwin` is a symbolic link to `kwin_x11` (Or vice versa) in kubuntu 18.04 , so either should work now